# Wix: Is it possible to remove/disable cancel button from uninstall UI (C#)?

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer

I am making an MSI installer with Wix, and would like to disable or completely remove the cancel button from the UI during uninstall. I have found [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/hiding-the-cancel-button-during-an-installation?redirectedfrom=MSDN) and I need to translate it to C#.
Is this possible at all or is there even a simpler way to get rid of the cancel button?

Comment: Why do you want to remove/disable Cancel button? Do you want to perform [quiet installation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31463516/1997232)?

Comment: I only want to remove the cancel button from the uninstallation UI, so that the user can't cancel in the middle of it. It's a demand on the uninstallation.